# How can I get the last day of the month's timestamp?

Tags: php, timestamp

I have the current unix timestamp stored in variable `$current_time`. Using this variable, I want to find out exactly what the timestamp is for the very last day of the current month.

How can I do this in PHP 5.4+?

Comment: This  `strtotime('last day of')` will give you timestamp of the last day of the current month. Reference here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: Or, if you specifically want it relative to the current month, `strtotime('last day of this month')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
// this is if your $current_time is not within the current month (although the code below is valid for every single month and every single timestamp)
$month = date("M", $current_time);

$last_day_timestamp = strtotime('last day of ' . $month);

echo date("d-m-Y", $last_day_timestamp);

// if your $current_time is within the current month
$last_day_timestamp_of_this_month = strtotime('last day of this month')
```

Also you could use this as a reference for other relative date/time formats:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php